# Can google cloud CDN be used for caching and scaling HLS (HTTP live streaming)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering if it's possible *or reasonable* to use **Google Cloud CDN** infrastructure for serving **HLS streams**. In theory, one would set `Cache-Control: max-age=<something low, like 10s>` on **HLS server** and point **CDN** to the **HLS server**. This would enable a nice caching layer while scaling the stream with no hussle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use Google Cloud CDN for serving HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) media.
Please check this cloud Solutions Architecture Reference for a use example at this [link](http://gcp.solutions/diagram/Live%20Streaming).